# the following android CustomAdapter does not work?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

Here is my completed android studio project coding:
i know i was made multiple errors but where??
i am very beginner

It is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

public Elements titles;
public ArrayList<String> news_list = new ArrayList<>();
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,news_list);
    new NewThread().execute();

}

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.varzesh3.com").get();

            titles = doc.getElementsByClass("small-news-link");

            news_list.clear();
            for (Element news : titles) {
                news_list.add(news.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }
}
```

}

And it is my CustomAdapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
List<String> listString;
Activity context;
Typeface typeFace;

public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<String> listString) {
    super(mainActivity, R.layout.list_item,listString);
    this.context = mainActivity;
    this.listString = listString;
}



static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.news);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/IRANSans.ttf");
    holder.textView.setTypeface(typeFace);


    return vi;
}
```

}`

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/news"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: The feeds from the site are not displayed

Comment: have you debugged? are the feeds coming from site??

Comment: @Airborne One thing I can suggest to set the adapter to list view in `onCreate` itself after creating the adapter. And then call `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. It looks like there is a lot going on here, and you might have trouble getting a good answer. Is the problem with the connection? Is it with your layouts, related to the font? Hard to tell. Your chances of getting a good answer are better if you create a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would suggest replacing the network code with some hard-coded text, and get rid of the font stuff. Maybe get rid of the async stuff too. Good luck!

Comment: @Sanjeet yes they come

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer thanks for help, i will do that

Answer (score 1):

In your `getView()` method of `CustomAdapter`, you never actually display any text. You inflate the view, create the `ViewHolder`, set the `Typeface`... but don't display any text. Add code that looks something like this:

```
String s = listString.get(position);
holder.textView.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ben P. Gave You the exact answer, You dont get the Strings from anywhere, You have just inflated the list_row without getting any acsual Strings.
I would advise You openinng a new class to handle the Strings/Objetcs with  an outside class lets say *StringClass* with getters and setters and put the `ArrayList<StringClass> list;` in the above and connect it to the adapter and after that just use it in the asynctask, easier and with OOP...
Cheers and good luck!